# Interop.Outlook keep running

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

Hei,

I have a problem with Interop.Outlook and I can't find solution. So I run my application where filter different Outlook's accounts with Interop.Outlook and get emails when needs. The application when start, open Outlook and get account to filter.
Also I use Outlook application for normals works.
So, sometimes filter didn't work and I think that when I close Outlook application, it close also in my application Interop.Outlook, so I have to restart my application to run the filter.

Have someone some ideas to keep running that or solutions to avoid to close Interop.Outlook?

`Application olApp;
    Account Acc;
    Items itemsInbox;
    MAPIFolder inbox;`

```
    public void FilterMain()
    {
        olApp = new Application();

        Accounts accounts = olApp.Session.Accounts;
        foreach (Account acc in accounts)
        {
            if (acc.SmtpAddress.ToLower() == "mail@mail.com")
            {
                Acc = acc;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (Acc != null)
        {
            Folders rootFolders = Acc.Session.Folders;

            foreach (Folder fold in rootFolders)
            {
                if (fold.Name.ToLower() == "mail@mail.com")
                {

                    foreach (Folder f in fold.Folders)
                    {
                        if (f.Name == "Saapuneet") //Saapuneet
                        {
                            inbox = f;
                            itemsInbox = inbox.Items;
                            itemsInbox.ItemAdd += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(ItemsInbox_ItemAdd);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to work with multiple accounts, are you sure Outlook is the right gateway for dealing with them? E.g. in a corporate Exchange environment, it's probably more sensible to be working directly against the exchange server rather than using a client application.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that Outlook was a simply way. However, I will try Exchange way, because I can't find other smart solution.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your code that retrieves an account does nothing - you never use Acc variable. Note that `Acc.Session` is the same as `olApp.Session`. You can use Account.DeliverToStore to retrieve the store for that account. You can then use `Store.GetRootFolder()` to retrieve its top level folder.

Secondly, Outlook closes when its last window is closed even if there are outstanding COM references to any of its objects. That was done to protect against buggy apps that leaked COM object references.

To keep Outlook alive, reference any of its `Explorer` or `Inspector` objects - you can retrieve one from `Application.ActiveExplorer` or call `MAPIFolder.GetExplorer`. The Explorer does not have to be visible.

Comment: Hi, thanks. However I'm testing Exchange and I think that for my applications runs really better, so I will change my code to EWS. However works in the same way, but there isn't Outlook application opening problem.